# iOS - Hide status bar on a click of a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, hide, statusbar

I got two buttons, `show` and `hide` button and I want to hide the status bar when the button hide is clicked I tried this method but it didn't work

```
- (IBAction)hide:(id)sender {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:
UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```

Is there is any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can simply set it's delegate :-

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

and called this method in to your method `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];`

Answer (score 1):

In your app's plist file add a row call it "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to NO.

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3 and iOS10**

This is how I'm using it with AVPlayer (not part of a question but on click is the same) with fullscreen support

```
private var fullscreenEnabled: Bool = false

func videoFullscreenButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton!) {
    if avPlayerLayer.videoGravity == AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill {
        avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
        fullscreenEnabled = false
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    } else {
        avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        fullscreenEnabled = true
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return fullscreenEnabled
}
```